# Mitmproxy routing

Tags: routes, mitmproxy

Goal: capture traffic from my mobile phone, even with ssl connection.

I set up a Laptop with a Ethernet connection.
Turned on a hotspot to share this connection to my mobile phone.
Followed the [Documentation](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/).
Internet on the phone is working perfectly fine until I enable the PREROUTING rules.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Why can't I access the Internet from the phone after applying these rules?

Thank you already for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to 1. enable port forwarding with setting

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

2. to capture SSL traffic you would use a tool called ssl-snarf, read up on it.
3. while you are statically setting the IP tables, I would use a tool like arpspoof instead.
this is assuming you are using Ubuntu.

Comment: sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 is set and
I couldn't find information about a tool called ssl-snarf, could you post a link?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks correct. It should work even with forwarding disabled.

1. Can you see incomming packets in tcpdump?  No> phone does not send anything
2. Do you see ICMP redirects?  Yes> sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.send_redirects=0
3. - Remove the PREROUTING rules
   - Start nc -lp 8080 instead of mitmproxy
   - Connect from the phone to to wlanIP:8080
   - Can netcat see the connection? No> local firewall blocks the connection